# Using Linq Calculate sum of ObservableCollection value

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my code sample

```
class Gold
{
    public String Category { get; set; }
    public Double Weight { get; set; }
}
class Metal
{
    public ObservableCollection<Gold> GoldCollection { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Double Amount { get; set; }
}
class Collection
{
    public ObservableCollection<Metal> MetalCollection { get; set; }
    public String Category { get; set; }
    public Double TotalWeight { get; set; }
}
```

How can I calculate Gold Weight, grouping by Category, from Collection model using LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Collection obj = new Collection();

obj.MetalCollection.SelectMany(m => m.GoldCollection).GroupBy(g => g.Category).Select(t => new { t.Key, MySum = t.Sum(n => n.Weight).ToString() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
var result = from m in collection.MetalCollection
             from g in m.GoldCollection
             group g by g.Category
             into gg
             select new
             {
                 Category = gg.Key,
                 Sum = gg.Sum(x => x.Weight)
             };
```